# An index with name 'primary' was already defined on table 'sites'

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using Doctrine 2 with ZF2.

I have a sites entity with the following primary key field.

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="site_id", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $siteId;
```

And the following index's

```
*   @ORM\Table(name="sites", indexes={
*   @ORM\Index(name="PRIMARY", columns={"site_id"}),
*   @ORM\Index(name="country_id", columns={"country_id"}),
*   @ORM\Index(name="timezone_id", columns={"timezone_id"}),
*   @ORM\Index(name="vat_rate_id", columns={"vat_rate_id"}),
*   @ORM\Index(name="site_mode_id", columns={"site_mode_id"}),
*   @ORM\Index(name="created_by_user_id", columns={"created_by_user_id"}),
* })
```

When I run `php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema` from the command line I get the following error message.

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
  An index with name 'primary' was already defined on table 'sites'.
```

However it also reports `The mapping files are correct.`

Does anyone know why this error is being generated?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT

Full entity as requested

```
/**
 * Sites Entity
 *
 * @author Garry Childs
 *
 *   @ORM\Table(name="sites", indexes={
 *   @ORM\Index(name="country_id", columns={"country_id"}),
 *   @ORM\Index(name="timezone_id", columns={"timezone_id"}),
 *   @ORM\Index(name="vat_rate_id", columns={"vat_rate_id"}),
 *   @ORM\Index(name="site_mode_id", columns={"site_mode_id"}),
 *   @ORM\Index(name="created_by_user_id", columns={"created_by_user_id"}),
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Entity\Repository\SitesRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Sites extends AbstractEntity
{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="site_id", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $siteId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="domain_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $domainName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email_address", type="string", length=254, nullable=false)
     */
    private $emailAddress;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="layout", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
     */
    private $layout;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="homepage", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
     */
    private $homepage;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bookmark_icon", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
     */
    private $bookmarkIcon = 'bookmark.png';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="town", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $town;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="county", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $county;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Countries
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Countries")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="country_id")
     * })
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="post_code", type="string", length=7, nullable=false)
     */
    private $postCode;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Timezones
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Timezones")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="timezone_id", referencedColumnName="timezone_id")
     * })
     */
    private $timezone;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="locale", type="string", length=5, nullable=false)
     */
    private $locale;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="currency_code", type="string", length=3, nullable=false)
     */
    private $currencyCode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vat_number", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     */
    private $vatNumber;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\VatRates
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\VatRates", inversedBy="sites")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vat_rate_id", referencedColumnName="vat_rate_id")
     * })
     */
    private $vatRate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_modified", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateModified;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by_user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $createdBy;

    /**
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Categories", mappedBy="site")
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SiteCountries", cascade="persist", mappedBy="site")
     */
    private $siteCountries;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SiteShippingMethods", cascade="persist", mappedBy="site")
     */
    private $shippingMethods;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SitePaymentMethods", cascade="persist", mappedBy="site")
     */
    private $sitePaymentMethods;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\SiteModes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SiteModes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_mode_id", referencedColumnName="site_mode_id")
     * })
     */
    private $siteMode;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="payment_days", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $paymentDays;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="products_per_page", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $productsPerPage;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Invoices", mappedBy="site")
     * })
     */
    private $invoices;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->siteCountries = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->shippingMethods = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->vatRate = NULL;
        $this->sitePaymentMethods = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->invoices = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->productsPerPage = 15;
    }

    .... Getters & Setters

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @return \Application\Entity\Users
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $this->getCurrentDateTime();
        $this->dateModified = $this->getCurrentDateTime();
        $this->currencyCode = $this->strToUpper($this->currencyCode);
        $this->createdBy = $this->getAuthUser();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     * @return \Application\Entity\Users
     */
    public function preUpdate()
    {
        $this->dateModified = $this->getCurrentDateTime();
        $this->currencyCode = $this->strToUpper($this->currencyCode);
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: that's because the name is recognised as a sql keyword. Try adding the backtick around the string `name="\`PRIMARY\`"`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have tried backticking PRIMARY with no luck, still getting the same error.

Comment: bcz the name PRIMARY is a MYSQL RESERVED keyword, inshort your error have your answer

Comment: I have just removed the line `*   @ORM\Index(name="`PRIMARY`", columns={"site_id"}),` and am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Garry What is inside your `AbstractEntity`? Did you already declare a primary key or identifier there?

Comment: @Wilt there is no entity definitions in the AbstractEntity just some variables  with getters & setters.

Comment: @Wilt I have also removed the `extends AbstractEntity` from the Sites entity and am still getting the same error,  I am wondering if this has something to do with the MySQL database table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already marked the `site_id` column as your primary column when you added `@ORM\Id` annotation to the  `$siteId` property. It is not necessary to add the following line:

```
@ORM\Index(name="PRIMARY", columns={"site_id"}),
```

Remove that line and you will see that the `site_id` column will be indexed properly as `PRIMARY` index automatically in your database.

Read more on this [in chapter **4.5. Identifiers / Primary Keys**](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys) in the doctrine documentation

Comment: I have removed the line `* @ORM\Index(name="PRIMARY", columns={"site_id"}),` and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Added entity definition to question as requested.

Comment: Just had the same issue on a ZF3 project so I followed @Wilt's advice and it worked so marking answer as correct.